# Why does the runnning time on virtual machine distribute strangely?

Tags: time, virtual-machine, virtualization

I wanted to test the execution time of the same program on a win10 virtual machine, so I ran this program for 100 times:

```
    for(int i=1;i<=1e8;i++)
    {

    }
```

And I drew a distribution picture(I have tested for many times and the result is similar):
[Distribution of execution time on virtual machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nWn3.png)

X is the running time, Y is the density.

It is strange because there are several peaks in this picture, and the X-coordinate of the peaks seem an arithmetic progression.

But on the guest machine, it is a normal distribution which is in line with our intuition.

I guess this is caused by some periodic process which occupies the cpu since I could only allocate 1 CPU to the virtual machine. Could you help me explain it?